# Cant get buttons from html calculator in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

i have a sample calculator html template

```
  <div id="container">
        <div id="display" class="t4"></div>
        <div id="buttons">
          <div class="t1">7</div>
          <div class="t1">8</div>
          <div class="t1">9</div>
          <div class="t1">/</div>

          <div class="t1">4</div>
          <div class="t1">5</div>
          <div class="t1">6</div>
          <div class="t1">*</div>

          <div class="t1">1</div>
          <div class="t1">2</div>
          <div class="t1">3</div>
          <div class="t1">-</div>

          <div class="t1">0</div>
          <div class="t1">.</div>
          <div class="t1">+</div>
          <div id="calculate"class="t1">=</div>
        </div>
```

where I want to add an event listener and get the value to be the operation/number to be executed,

but whenever I try to get the div's in a variable in my javascript file, it just turns out to be null

```
const keys = document.querySelector('buttons');
console.log(keys)
```

i have also tried with the `document.getElementById` function

with no luck.. is it because I'm not inside a function or is it because I',m assigning it to a value?

when I do it inside a function

```
function myFunction() {
const buttons =document.getElementById('buttons')
console.log(buttons)
}
```

it works fine?

Comment: `document.getElementById('buttons')` should work. Or `document.querySelector('#buttons')`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Comment: The linked question concerns jquery not vanilla JS

Comment: you have to learn about delegate event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key issue is that you're using `querySelector`, but not passing a proper `CSS` style selector like `.class` or `#id`. You have a few options for getting all your "buttons" based on your existing classes or your id.

I'd highly suggest using `getElementsByClassName` as it is the most performant solution.

You can use one of the following

```
document.getElementsByClassName('t1')

document.getElementById('buttons').children

document.querySelectorAll('.t1')
```

#### Demo

```js
var buttons1 = document.getElementsByClassName('t1');
var buttons2 = document.getElementById('buttons').children;
var buttons3 = document.querySelectorAll('.t1');

console.log(buttons1);
console.log(buttons2);
console.log(buttons3);
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="display" class="t4"></div>
  <div id="buttons">
    <div class="t1">7</div>
    <div class="t1">8</div>
    <div class="t1">9</div>
    <div class="t1">/</div>

    <div class="t1">4</div>
    <div class="t1">5</div>
    <div class="t1">6</div>
    <div class="t1">*</div>

    <div class="t1">1</div>
    <div class="t1">2</div>
    <div class="t1">3</div>
    <div class="t1">-</div>

    <div class="t1">0</div>
    <div class="t1">.</div>
    <div class="t1">+</div>
    <div id="calculate"class="t1">=</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Performance Test

https://jsperf.com/so53905199

#### Documentation

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

Answer (score 2):

Try to execute the code after pageload

Answer (score 1):

No need to have 16 events listeners. As I said in my comment. You have to use event delegation.

```js
var strValue = '';

document.querySelector('#buttons').onclick = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (e.target.className != 't1') return;

  switch (e.target.textContent){
    case '-':
      console.log('--> sub')
    break
    case '+':
      console.log('--> add')
    break
    case '/':
      console.log('--> div')
    break
    case '*':
      console.log('--> multiply')
    break
    case '=':
      console.log('--> calculate')
    break
    default:
      strValue += e.target.textContent;
      console.log(strValue)
    }
}
```

```css
    #buttons {
      display : block;
      width   : 110px;
      font-size: 16px
    }
    #buttons>div {
      display : block;
      float: left;
      margin : 2px;
      width   : 20px;
      height  : 20px;
      border : 1px solid grey;
      text-align: center;
      line-height: 1.4em;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    #buttons>div:hover {
      background-color: yellow;
    }
```

```html
<div id="buttons">
  <div class="t1">7</div>
  <div class="t1">8</div>
  <div class="t1">9</div>
  <div class="t1">/</div>

  <div class="t1">4</div>
  <div class="t1">5</div>
  <div class="t1">6</div>
  <div class="t1">*</div>

  <div class="t1">1</div>
  <div class="t1">2</div>
  <div class="t1">3</div>
  <div class="t1">-</div>

  <div class="t1">0</div>
  <div class="t1">.</div>
  <div class="t1">+</div>
  <div id="calculate" class="t1">=</div>
</div>
```